# Check if one event is identical to another during event retargeting in older Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6, dom-events

If you try this in Internet Explorer you can see that the dispatched event is not unique during bubbling:

```
var x;
myinnerdiv.onclick = function() { x = window.event; };
myparentdiv.onclick = function() { alert(x === window.event); };
// false, but should be the same!
```

Using the equivalent standards-based method:

```
var x;
myinnerdiv.onclick = function(ev) { x = ev; };
myparentdiv.onclick = function(ev) { alert(x === ev); };
// true: same event, retargeted
```

Is there a way to uniquely identify an event in code to work around this lack of functionality?

Comment: It's an object, if you want to extend it, just do so: `ev.mySuperSpecialInfo = 42;`. Even better, use your own system to store state. `var eventState = 'reachedParent';`

Comment: as i said ev.mySuperSpecialInfo is not dispatched in myparentdiv, because they are two totally different objects

Comment: I thought you're using the second version? If not, you should be.

Comment: @davin but IE does not pass the `event` object as a parameter to the function.  It's a global (that is, a property of `window`).

Comment: Indeed! Note to self: best not to comment when asleep and dealing with old versions of IE. Still you can store your own state-machine. You should be able to perform primitive things without even that: referring to the `target` attribute you should be able to discern whether you're in a parent or the actual element (if you don't need to know where you are in a more deeply nested DOM structure)

Comment: yup old versions of IE uses window.event to store the event object... it is not the same instance during event bubbling. when the event is retargeted, a window.event is assigned with one brand new object

Comment: I can use, for sure .srcElement (equivalent of .target) if the event is at target or it is bubbling up dom, but it is not what I've asked... I want that all IE-event-objects used during bubbling are identifiable as an unique one... I don't want to fix the impossible, it's just an hacker thing, but I want to know if there is some way to do this

Comment: setting some flag for a specific case is obviously a solution, but I'm looking for something that will be always available, as feature, for every case

Comment: Maybe you can set a flag with the object that was initially targeted by the event. The next time the handler is called, you check to see if the cached object is a child of the targeted object. If it is, you know the event isn't unique, and you could even grab a cached event object.

Comment: @cptroot feel free to answer ;) no need for cross browser code, internet explorer only code is fine (ie no need for evt = evt || window.event)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`window.event` is not a data value but a getter function to create event objects. Much like most
of the DOM properties are not data values but accessor functions.

You can even do them next to each other:

```
div.onclick = function() {
    var a = window.event;
    var b = window.event;
    alert( a === b ) // false
};
```

Anyway, just make your own function:

```
window.getEvent = (function() {
    var e = {};

    return function() {
        var cur = window.event;
        if( cur.type === e.type &&
            cur.srcElement === e.srcElement &&
            cur.clientX === e.clientX &&
            cur.clientY === e.clientY &&
            cur.keyCode === e.keyCode ) {
            return e.evt;
        }
        e.type = cur.type;
        e.srcElement = cur.srcElement;
        e.clientX = cur.clientX;
        e.clientY = cur.clientY;
        e.keyCode = cur.keyCode;
        e.evt = cur;
        return cur;
    };
})();

myinnerdiv.onclick = function () {
    var event = getEvent();
    event.myCustomProp = 3;
};
myparentdiv.onclick = function () {
    var event = getEvent();
    alert( event.myCustomProp === 3 );
};
```

It assumes that these 5 values are enough to see if the event objects represent the same event, which seems reasonable to me.

[Test page here](http://jsfiddle.net/FLynK/show/), precisely click the text 'asd' (red colored), as the html is:

```
<div id="myparentdiv">
    daa
    <div id="myinnerdiv">asd</div>
    daa
</div>
```

If you want something that works for sure then just use jQuery, you basically have to create an entire event model from scratch
to do this more cleanly (and always use that event model's API).

Answer (score 1):

A simple way: just compare event1.timeStamp and event2.timeStamp

Comment: That would have not been simple even if it worked in IE6-8 since 2 different events can easily have same timestamp.